# Regular expression for removing all chars in the text except for permitted ones

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to write a Python function that inputs a text and substitute every character that is not specified in VALID_CHARS with the whitespace ' '. Any way to do it using regex?

The regex solution should do the same as the following Python code:

```
def clean_text(text):
    text_valid = ''
    for char in text:
        if char in VALID_CHARS:
            text_valid += char
        else:
            text_valid += ' '
    return text_valid
```

Comment: What's in `VALID_CHARS` and why do you want to use a regex? Your code is fine and probably faster. The regex is simply `"[" + VALID_CHARS + "]"` with some minor tweaks if `VALID_CHARS` could contain `]`, `[`, or `-`.

Comment: @tripleee for my case VALID_CHARS is all English and Russian symbols ('A-я') + whitespace. I was looking for regex solution because I though it might be shorter, simpler and faster.

Comment: @tripleee In my case, VALID_CHARS = (' ' + string.letters + u'АаБбВвГгДдЕеЁёЖжЗзИиЙйКкЛлМмНнОоПпРрСсТтУуФфХхЦцЧчШшЩщЪъЫыЬьЭэЮюЯя') . Are you aware of how this can be reduced to a regular expression?

Comment: If speed is really crucial (which honestly I don't believe it is here) then you should be looking at [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a regular expression based on `VALID_CHARS` on the fly and use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
import re

def clean_text(text):
    regex = '[^' + re.escape(VALID_CHARS) + ']'
    return re.sub(regex, ' ', text)
```

[`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#re.escape) ensures that characters like `]` won't break the regular expression.

Comment: `re.escape` isn't really correct inside a character class, which obeys a different syntax than genuine regular expressions. In ide a character class, only a leading `^` and a non-leading `-` are strictly metacharacters.

Comment: I guess having it won't hurt either?

Comment: If it changes `\n` to `\\n` for example, that could produce a pretty hard-to-diagnose bug.

Comment: Having `\n` in both `VALID_CHARS` and `text` should work as expected as it's actually a single (newline) character.

Comment: But `re.escape` would then turn it into a backslash and a literal `n` in the character class.

Comment: Why? It will be a backslash and a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the library [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) that might help you.

I think this should work: `text_valid = re.sub(re.compile('[^'+re.escape(VALID_CHARS)+']'), r'', text)`

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
re.sub(r'[^{}]'.format(re.escape(VALID_CHARS)), '', text)
```